# Javascript Object agregation: cannot call method of inner object

Tags: javascript, oop, aggregation, inner-classes

I am starting Javascript and I get quite confused with the way objects are managed.
Following this article http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html, I made some tests with this code:

```
var Person= function() {
    // Constructor
    function Person(name) {
        this.name = name;
    };
};
Person.prototype.hello= function() {
    return "Hello I am "+this.name;
};
// Object containing other object
var Couple= function() {
  // Constructor
  function Couple() {
     this.dad= new Person("Dad");
     this.mom= new Person("Mom");
   };
};
Couple.prototype.introduce= function() {
   return this.dad.hello();
};
var family = new Couple();
alert(family.introduce());
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined` on the line defining the introduce function...

I tried saving the this context in the constructor functions and using it in the `hello()` and `introduce()` methods instead but this changes nothing...
I feel silly to no beiing able to make these simple trick, but I found no obvious solution...
What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: don't nest constructors like that; the outer Couple() doesn't return anything, so it's not something that works with "new ". same with your Person()s

Comment: Thanks! I simplified the code by only declaring the constructor function with: ` // Constructor
  function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
};` and the same for Couple, then it works...Seems odd though to declare a class with just a function but I guess it is the Javascript magic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your inner, hoisted function only exists within a private scope, and isn't overriding it's parent even though it shares the same name, because it's newly declared

When you use `var fn = function () {}` it will exist where defined

When you use `function fn () {}` it will be available to code written above itself, because it's hoisted

Eg:

```
doSomething(); // will actually perform correctly because definition below gets hoisted

function doSomething () {}
```

---

```
doSomething(); // will throw error because doSomething didn't get assigned yet, even though the variable doSomething was hoisted

var doSomething = function () {};
```